# Why does my terminal show a string like this?

Tags: macos, terminal

When I open my terminal it shows this:

```
wpa-2-602:~ david$
```

I just curious what the `wpa-2-602` means? "david" is my user name, and sometimes it was something else. What makes it change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's based on the `PS1` variable set in Bash's initialization. Yours appears to be the default, which is your computer's name, followed by a colon, then the current directory (in your example, that'd be the home directory for your computer [~]), then your username (david).

[Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) is an article about customizing your PS1, and there are plenty of questions both here and over at [Super User](https://superuser.com/) about changing and fixing it.

Comment: The computer's name will be used unless the dhcp client get's another host name when connecting to a network.  My guess is that the OP is noticing the name change when he's on a network whose dhcp server actually responds to the host name request from his computer.

Comment: Any particular complaint from the downvoter?